# PythonでのBOTの作り方通りに作っても動かない: App not compatible with buildpack

Tags: python, git, heroku, google-api, discord

[PythonでDiscordのTRPG用のダイスボットを自作してみた - Qiita](https://qiita.com/Sashimimochi/items/3cbea852f133fed5d44b)

上記サイトの手順通り、GitからforkしてHerokuで動かそうとしたのですが、

```
-----> App not compatible with buildpack: https://buildpack-registry.s3.amazonaws.com/buildpacks/heroku/python.tgz
       More info: https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/buildpacks#detection-failure
 !     Push failed
```

となってしまい、デプロイすることができません。

念のため、GitHub リポジトリは以下になります。

[RTa-technology/discord_dice_bot](https://github.com/RTa-technology/discord_dice_bot/tree/94f375e09f96bc8776c33e2cf6a51cd3035a73df)

どなたか原因などわかる方がおられましたらご教授いただければ幸いです。
よろしくお願いいたします。

Comment: リポジトリ内のファイルに OAuth 2.0 の client_secret が埋め込まれています。現時点で利用している client_secret を revoke してファイルを削除される事をお勧めします。

Comment: 追記部分は最初の質問とエラーメッセージが変わっており原因も別の箇所になったことが予想されるため、新しく別の質問として投稿していただけると Q&A しやすいです。よろしくお願いします。

Comment: @metropolis さん、削除いたしました。ありがとうございます。

Comment: @nekketsuuu さん、そうですね。新しく投稿します。ありがとうございます。

Answer (score 1, accepted):

ファイル名が間違っています。 `requirement.txt` ではなく `requirements.txt` です。この回答を投稿した時点では、元の記事から間違っていますね。

---

以下、どのようにしてこれに気付いたかのログです。

まずエラーメッセージを読むと、Python buildpack に合致してない、というエラーが出ています。詳細は https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/buildpacks#detection-failure を読めと書いてあるので読みます。

すると Heroku ではそれぞれの buildpack が「自分向けのプロジェクトかどうか」を検出するための detection script を持っており、これに弾かれると類似のエラーが出ると分かります。

そこで Python buildpack の [`bin/detect`](https://github.com/heroku/heroku-buildpack-python/blob/61609930c167e04ea4b41027e725ac46f7270e72/bin/detect) を読んでみました。こう書かれています。

```
# Exit early if app is clearly not Python.
if [ ! -f "$BUILD_DIR/requirements.txt" ] && [ ! -f "$BUILD_DIR/setup.py" ] && [ ! -f "$BUILD_DIR/Pipfile" ]; then
  exit 1
fi
```

Python のプロジェクトかどうかを、`requirements.txt`、`setup.py`、`Pipfile` のどれかがあるかどうかで判定しています。

今回のプロジェクトでは `requirements.txt` を使おうとしています。そこでファイルを確認してみるとファイル名が間違っていると気付きました。

Comment: ありがとうございます。
ファイル名を修正しました。
質問の追記を致しました。