# Discord.pyでの構文エラーが発生する

Tags: python, discord

[RTa-technology/discord_dice_bot](https://github.com/RTa-technology/discord_dice_bot/tree/87b0104bb3a72524777568312bfff4542700dc92)
このプログラムを実行した結果Herokuでのデプロイは完了したのですが、Discordの方でオンラインになりません (恐らくコードが間違っている可能性が大きい)。

HerokuとGithubを連携させており、Heroku上では `Build succeeded` となる為エラーが起こっていないと思われました。しかしオンラインにならないため何か間違えていそうです。ただ、Github上ではエラーが発生している場所を特定する方法が不明でした。

[前回の質問](https://ja.stackoverflow.com/questions/65339/python%E3%81%A7%E3%81%AEbot%E3%81%AE%E4%BD%9C%E3%82%8A%E6%96%B9%E9%80%9A%E3%82%8A%E3%81%AB%E4%BD%9C%E3%81%A3%E3%81%A6%E3%82%82%E5%8B%95%E3%81%8B%E3%81%AA%E3%81%84-app-not-compatible-with-buildpack)からコードを編集してGoogle Spread Sheetの方にアクセスするのではなくリスト化したものからの読み込みを行っています。

コードが間違っている場合、どの部分が間違っているのか申し訳ないのですがわかりません。

可能であれば、どの部分が間違っているのかお教えいただければ嬉しく思います。

---

04/10 00:00 追記
[このよう](https://github.com/RTa-technology/discord_dice_bot/tree/c60fbd16f7fcd76031337e886bb65277a57189da)に編集しました。
変更履歴

```
bot
の変数を
client
に変更
```

しました。

結果 Herokuのlogでは

```
2020-04-09T14:57:15.856251+00:00 app[worker.1]: Traceback (most recent call last):
2020-04-09T14:57:15.856315+00:00 app[worker.1]:   File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.6/site-packages/discord/client.py", line 312, in _run_event
2020-04-09T14:57:15.856316+00:00 app[worker.1]:     await coro(*args, **kwargs)
2020-04-09T14:57:15.856321+00:00 app[worker.1]:   File "trpg_bot.py", line 512, in on_message
2020-04-09T14:57:15.856322+00:00 app[worker.1]:     input_msg = bot_startswitch(message).fixed
2020-04-09T14:57:15.856366+00:00 app[worker.1]: AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'fixed'
2020-04-09T14:57:21.096405+00:00 heroku[worker.1]: State changed from up to down
2020-04-09T14:57:20.879678+00:00 app[api]: Deploy c60fbd16 by user XXXXX@gmail.com
2020-04-09T14:57:20.879678+00:00 app[api]: Release v28 created by user XXXXX@gmail.com
2020-04-09T14:57:33.000000+00:00 app[api]: Build succeeded
```

となり、Botは起動しましたが、何も返信が返ってきません。

---

2020/04/09 23:49 追記

```
2020-04-09T12:10:11.727817+00:00 app[woker.1]:   File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.6/site-packages/discord/client.py", line 312, in _run_event
2020-04-09T12:10:11.727818+00:00 app[woker.1]:     await coro(*args, **kwargs)
2020-04-09T12:10:11.727850+00:00 app[woker.1]:   File "trpg_bot.py", line 510, in on_message
2020-04-09T12:10:11.727851+00:00 app[woker.1]:     if client.user != message.author:
2020-04-09T12:10:11.727906+00:00 app[woker.1]: NameError: name 'client' is not defined
2020-04-09T14:42:29.000000+00:00 app[api]: Build started by user XXXXXXXX@gmail.com
2020-04-09T14:43:02.795195+00:00 heroku[woker.1]: State changed from up to down
2020-04-09T14:43:02.717678+00:00 app[api]: Deploy 1a8e0369 by user XXXXXXXX@gmail.com
2020-04-09T14:43:02.717678+00:00 app[api]: Release v23 created by user XXXXXXXX@gmail.com
2020-04-09T14:43:15.000000+00:00 app[api]: Build succeeded
```

とエラーが出ていたので、

```
if client.user
を
if bot.user
に変更し
```

修正いたしました。

Comment: python の場合、変数名の最初の文字に数字を使う事ができないのと、`.`(dot) を含めることができないので、例えば `4176.col_keys` という変数名は syntax error になります。

Comment: ソースへのリンクの飛び先がdiff結果になってるので直しましょう。そして「構文エラーが発生する」のなら、何時何処で発生して、そのエラーメッセージは何かといった詳細な情報を正しく記述しておかないと、回答が得られ難いですよ。

Comment: @kunif さん、コメントいただきありがとうございます。diffの部分を修正しました。
kunifさんのおっしゃる、詳細な方法なのですが、HerokuとGithubを連携させており、その場合、Heroku上では
`Build succeeded`となる為エラーが起こっていないと思われました。また、Github上ではエラーが発生している場所を特定する方法が不明でした為、書いておりませんでした。

Comment: @RTa_technology さん、コメントだと質問内容の更新が一人にしか通知されないため、エラー内容の更新などは質問文に直接追記し、必要であれば追記したことをコメントで通知する、という形にしてみてください。質問文を更新すると質問リストの上に来るので見てもらいやすくなります。　／　また GitHub ではリポジトリ上で Y キーを押すとコミットハッシュを含めた URL を得ることができます。? キーでヘルプが見られます。ご参考までに。

Comment: ありがとうございます。前より言われていたのにそうできていなかった自分を申し訳なく感じております。Githubは最近使い始めたばっかりなのでそういうことができるのかと感心しております。取得したものを追記しました。

Answer (score 1):

通りがかりですまないが、`Procfile`を見る限り、

```
woker: python trpg_bot.py
```

は `woker` ではなく `worker` ではないだろうか。`r` が抜けている。

```
worker: python trpg_bot.py
```

Herokuのフリープランは30分でスリープするのでこのボットが動き続けるかも定かではないが……。

また、どのような時もまずはHerokuのダッシュボードでアプリのページの「More :」メニューから「View logs」を開き、起動後に期待するログを吐いているか確認してほしい。

Comment: workerにすると、Herokuの方で記述内容の縛りがかかってしまうために誤字にしているのだと考えました。
view logの方を記述いたしました。
ありがとうございます。

Answer (score 0):

python の場合、変数名の最初の文字に数字を使う事ができないのと、`.`(dot) を含めることができないので、例えば `4176.col_keys` という変数名は syntax error になります。

<sub>-- この回答は [metropolis](https://ja.stackoverflow.com/users/16894/metropolis) さんの[コメント](https://ja.stackoverflow.com/questions/65473/discord-py%E3%81%A7%E3%81%AE%E6%A7%8B%E6%96%87%E3%82%A8%E3%83%A9%E3%83%BC%E3%81%8C%E7%99%BA%E7%94%9F%E3%81%99%E3%82%8B#comment71753_65473)をコミュニティ wiki として投稿するものです。</sub>

Comment: ありがとうございます。
変数名をcol_keys_4176などに変更しました。